# How to update database from change made in livecode datagrid

Tags: datagrid, livecode

I have a datagrid in livecode. I want to update the data in the underlying database after the user have made a change in a row of the datagrid

Hi Malte,

That's looking very promising. The only problem is that the name field in the database table is not the same as the column name. I wanted to use an sql update statement to update the database. I tried the following code

```
on CloseFieldEditor pFieldEditor

--Connect to database
  databaseConnect
--Update Record

put  GetDataOfLine( the dgHilitedlines of me,"Pathogen") into strPathogen
put  GetDataOfLine( the dgHilitedlines of me,"Offset") into strIncubation
put  GetDataOfLine( the dgHilitedlines of me,"Duration") into     strDurationofIllness
put  GetDataOfLine( the dgHilitedlines of me,"ID") into IntID

put "UPDATE  tblPathogen SET fldPathogenName='" & strPathogen & "',     fldIncubation='" & strIncubation &  "', fldDurationofIllness='" &     strDurationofIllness & "'" into strSQL
put " WHERE fldPathogenID=" & IntID after strsql

put strsql into field "test"

--SaveDataToDatabase theTable, theRowID, theColumnBeingEdited, theNewText

end CloseFieldEditor
```

The problem is that the value in the grid change back to the original value before being assigned to the variables. How do I update the grid to hold the text of pFieldEditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not override the stndard datagrid behaviour by using your own template, a CloseFieldEditor message is sent to the grid control. You can use that message to react to the change of data and trigger a handler which stores the data in a database.

The problem here is though that you trap the handler that actually updates the datagrid. In a regular case the data of the datagrid is updated AFTER the message is executed. So in your case, you will want to update the data yourself...

Modified script:

```
on CloseFieldEditor pFieldEditor
   -- declared locals to make it compile in strict mode
   local strPathogen,strIncubation,strDurationOfIllness,intID,strSQL
   local theColumnBeingEdited,tLineDataArray
   local tNewText


   put the text of pFieldEditor into tNewText
   -- this holds the value the user entered

   put the dgColumn of the target into theColumnBeingEdited
   -- find the column that has been changed

   put the dgDataOfLine[the dgHilitedLine of me] of me into tLineDataArray
   -- get the whole line of data and put it into an array

   put tNewText into tLinedataArray[theColumnBeingEdited]
   -- update the col in the array accordingly

   set the dgDataOfLine[the dgHilitedLine of me] of me to tLineDataArray
   -- update data in grid

   --Connect to database
   databaseConnect
   --Update Record

   put  GetDataOfLine( the dgHilitedlines of me,"Pathogen") into strPathogen
   put  GetDataOfLine( the dgHilitedlines of me,"Offset") into strIncubation
   put  GetDataOfLine( the dgHilitedlines of me,"Duration") into     strDurationofIllness
   put  GetDataOfLine( the dgHilitedlines of me,"ID") into IntID

   put "UPDATE  tblPathogen SET fldPathogenName='" & strPathogen & "',     fldIncubation='" & strIncubation &  "', fldDurationofIllness='" &     strDurationofIllness & "'" into strSQL
   put " WHERE fldPathogenID=" & IntID after strsql

   put strsql into field "test"

   --SaveDataToDatabase theTable, theRowID, theColumnBeingEdited, theNewText

end CloseFieldEditor
```

This is explained quite nicely over here: http://lessons.runrev.com/m/datagrid/l/7337-how-do-i-save-changes-the-user-makes-in-an-editor-field-to-an-external-data-source

Keep in mind that the scripts are not optimized for strict compilation mode though (which I always recommend using, as it saves you from shooting your own foot). If you want the script to compile in strict mode, you would also need to declare the variables.

Comment: HI Malte, Thanks for your response. I just need some clarifications. The link suggest using the CloseFieldEditor handle but it's not clear when this event is triggered. I tried the following code to test the trigger and nothing happened
`
on CloseFieldEditor pFieldEditor
   
    answer "CloseFieldEditor"
   
end CloseFieldEditor
`

Comment: Hi Sheils, the rCloseFieldEditor message is triggered once the field the user types in disappears (the user hits return, or TABs out of the field in question) unless of course you set up the datagrid with a template that lets you directly edit in the grid overriding using the standard behavior.

Comment: Hi Malte, see my additional question in my aswer below

Comment: HI Malte, Thanks a lot that works fine. However, you just missed a little thing. With your code all the other data in the line is delete so I put the whole line in the array then updated the array with the following code

  -- update the col in the array accordingly
   put the dgDataOfLine[the dgHilitedLine of me] of me into tLinedataArray
   put strNewText into tLinedataArray[theColumnBeingEdited]